# module makefile fails for armv7l when modules are compressed

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-modules, make

I have written a network hook using netfilter. This modules compiles successfully on my ubuntu 16.04.

Now I want to compile it in my embedded board which uses a customized Linux using same version of kernel in my laptop. The only problem is that all the modules in my embedded board are in `.ko.xz` format and my makefile fails and I don't know how to solve the problem.

My original makefile is:

```
obj-m += sysfirewall.o
all:
    make -C  /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build -I/usr/Include/ M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build -I/usr/Include/ M=$(PWD) clean
```

But this failed because I couldn't find any build folder in my embedded Linux. Instead of build folder there was a kernel folder which I replace it with kernel.

Now my makefile is:

```
obj-m += sysfirewall.o
all:
    make -C  /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/kernel -I/usr/Include/ M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/kernel -I/usr/Include/ M=$(PWD) clean
```

But when I run make in the current directory it gives the following error:

```
$ make -C  /lib/modules/4.14.49-ti-r54/kernel -I/usr/Include/ M=/home/parsa/firewall/ modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/lib/modules/4.14.49-ti-r54/kernel'
make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'modules'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/lib/modules/4.14.49-ti-r54/kernel'9-ti-r54/uname -i 
Makefile:3: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

How can I solve this problem? Should I uncompress all the modules in my kernel?
Does it really a matter of compressed Linux kernel modules or the error shows something else?

P.S: I don't want to cross-compile the module in my laptop.

Edited: 
I noticed there should be a Makefile in the "/lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/kernel" folder which is not in my embedded board. 
I traced the Make file in "/lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build" folder in my laptop and realized it is a soft link to /usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-128/Makefile. but I don't have anything in my /usr/src in my embedded board. so I think I have to find a make file in order to compile this module and I don't know how !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with the compression, but with the `make` not finding the correct files. Note that the make command is entering the `/lib/modules/<kernel version>/kernel` directory, and only then reporting an error. So it's not finding whatever it needs in there.

You cannot substitute `/lib/modules/<kernel version>/kernel` to `/lib/modules/<kernel version>/build`: their contents are different. The `kernel` directory contains the already-compiled modules that came with that particular kernel version. That does not help the `make` command at all: it needs the makefiles and `.h` files that come with the kernel source code. Some of those are dynamically generated as part of the main kernel compilation.

Normally, the `/lib/modules/<kernel version>/build` is a symbolic link pointing to wherever the kernel headers associated with that particular kernel version are located. If your embedded board uses a kernel that has been compiled in "the Debian way" (i.e. with `make bindeb-pkg` or similar in the kernel source directory), the kernel compilation process should have produced a number of `.deb` packages:

- `linux-image-<version>_<patchversion>_<architecture>.deb` = the actual compiled kernel and its modules
- `linux-headers-<version>_<patchversion>_<architecture>.deb` = the headers you'll need to compile further kernel modules for this specific kernel

In that case, you'll only need to find and install the `linux-headers` package corresponding to the exact kernel version you're using in your ARM board. It will automatically provide the `/lib/modules/<kernel version>/build` link for you.

If you have compiled your own custom kernel with traditional `make bzimage` or similar, then you'll have to provide the `/lib/modules/<kernel version>/build` link yourself. If you have the actual kernel build directory still available, just link it to `/lib/modules/<kernel version>/build`.